# How is webservice different than a website

Tags: web-services, web

From what I have gathered from various sources:

- A website provides and presents data
- A webservice provides data and there is no presentation involved.

Both are called using an url.

But webservice does return data in forms like xml , json etc. How is it any different than a website then which is returning it in the form of an html?

Answer (score 0):

**Website:**

1. Website is a set of related web pages located under a single domain
   name.
2. It serves the user html typically to be interpreted and displayed in
   a web browser to a user.
3. This is the typical GET request over HTTP(S).

**Web service**

4. A web service is any piece of software that makes itself available
   over the Internet and uses a standardized XML/JSON messaging system.
5. For example, a client invokes a web service by sending an XML/JSON
   The message, then waits for a corresponding XML/JSON response.
6. The web service can respond to many different types of requests
   (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE etc).
7. Interacting with a web service can result in changing data on a
   remote location, getting information back regarding some data etc.
8. Furthermore, a web service can respond in many different ways,
   serving data in text, XML or even an empty response. Requests to web services are usually obfuscated from the user.

Comment: What does - _Requests to web services are usually obfuscated form the user_ mean ??

Comment: It simply means It would not be easy to use for end users if they do not have web services documentation. While a website is easy to use by looking at interface(UI). Web services do not have any UI.